# PHP: How can I take an input from the user, store it, and display it back?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been trying to create some php code that would let me 
take input from a user using a text box. I want to then store 
that input (probably like 7 characters long) and then display it 
on a page in a list format ( eg
1
2
3
)

I've been at this for hours reading tutorials and what not but everything
I find only shows me the fwrite function and when I try to append I still
end up deleting data.

I would like the newest inputs to show up on top of the list if possible.

Can someone help me?
I am really frustrated and I know almost no php.. kind of playing around
with it and can't figure this out =/

I was thinking of storing the input from users in an array, then display the array..
But that doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to have a form, let the users enter text, then display all the text entered by all the users, sort of like a wall or guestbook.

I'm presuming you've managed to fetch the user's input by looking at `$_POST` after the form submission. To store it in a file without overwriting the existing file contents the easiest way is `file_put_contents` with the special `FILE_APPEND` flag.

Lets say your HTML form has a textbox with `name="newData"`. Then, in the form submission target script:

```
//store all user input in a file called data.txt in the current directory
$filename = "./data.txt" ;
$newData = $_POST['newData'] . "\n" ;
file_put_contents($filename, $newData, FILE_APPEND);

//now fetch all data and display it
$lines = file($filename) ; 

echo '<ul>' ;

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo "<li>$line</li>" ;
}

echo '</ul>' ;
```

Get started like that to see the basics in action and then you can look into:

- filtering user input so that you don't store and display any nasty stuff
- storing the data file outside the web root so that it's not accessible via the browser
- prettifying the output list

Comment: Thank you so much Fanis! It works great!! Do you have any recommendations as to where I should do some research or what should I read to do the filtering and other things you suggested?

Comment: The idea is that you can't trust user input. Users may want to add dangerous data that, when you display in your HTML (eg your wall), will run some nasty javascript, steal other users' cookies etc. So you should filter user input and escape output. For starters you should `$newData = htmlentities($_POST['newData'] . "\n" ;` http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-scripting - http://www.lazycat.org/php-filtering.php which talks about `filter_input()`

Answer (score 2):

If they're submitting the data via form, it will POST to the server; meaning you can use:

```
<form action="target.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit value="Submit" />
</form>
```

for the markup, and then for the PHP (on target.php):

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) { //to check if the form was submitted
        $username= $_POST['username'];
    } 
?>
```

At this point you can then use `<?php echo $username ?>` anywhere you want to echo the data entered from the previous page.

I'm no PHP expert either (I recommend the Lynda.com training videos, "PHP & MySQL Essential Training" and "PHP & MySQL Beyond The Basics" with Kevin Skoglund) but maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you can use `$_POST` to get the data, however it is worth noting that if you are actually using this in a web application, you need to sanitize for [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You can do this quite simply with PHP's [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this for taking input from user in php

$variablname = fgets(STDIN);
echo $variable;

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents('/path/to/file','contents',FILE_APPEND);
```